# Error using categoricalFeaturesInfo in pyspark mllib Decision tree classifier

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am executing a DecisionTree classifier for pyspark mllib and am running into an issue when I provide a dictionary object stored in a variable to a categoricalFeaturesInfo vs when I provide the dictionary directly.Following is the code in both the cases

**case1)cat_counts={1: 12, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 3, 10: 12, 15: 4}
DecisionTree.trainClassifier(data,numClasses=2,categoricalFeaturesInfo=cat_counts,impurity='gini')**

**case2)DecisionTree.trainClassifier(data,numClasses=2,categoricalFeaturesInfo={1: 12, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 3, 10: 12, 15: 4},impurity='gini')**

**Case2** gets executed without any error but, the **case 1** throws the **error** listed below.
In both the cases I am providing the same dictionary containing the mapping of indices and unique levels in each categorical attributes.

> An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe.loads. :
>   net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for
>   construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)   at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
>     at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)   at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)   at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)    at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)  at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe$.loads(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1475)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe.loads(PythonMLLibAPI.scala)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/var/tmp/spark/4550967606900043523", line 90, in execute
>       exec code in global_dict   File "", line 1, in    File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/mllib/tree.py",
>   line 206, in trainClassifier
>       impurity, maxDepth, maxBins, minInstancesPerNode, minInfoGain)   File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/mllib/tree.py",
>   line 146, in _train
>       impurity, maxDepth, maxBins, minInstancesPerNode, minInfoGain)   File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py",
>   line 130, in callMLlibFunc
>       return callJavaFunc(sc, api, *args)   File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line
>   122, in callJavaFunc
>       args = [_py2java(sc, a) for a in args]   File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line
>   88, in _py2java
>       obj = sc._jvm.SerDe.loads(data)   File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 813, in **call**
>       answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)   File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45,
>   in deco
>       return f(*a, **kw)   File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 308, in get_return_value
>       format(target_id, ".", name), value) Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe.loads. :
>   net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for
>   construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)   at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
>     at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)   at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)   at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)    at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)  at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe$.loads(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1475)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe.loads(PythonMLLibAPI.scala)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

From that error I could trace that it occurs when doing the following thing
**PickleSerializer().dumps(obj)**

So, I checked the following
*PickleSerializer().dumps(cat_Counts)*-which gives the following output

> '\x80\x02}q\x01(cnumpy.core.multiarray\nscalar\nq\x02cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x03U\x02i8K\x00K\x01\x87Rq\x04(K\x03U\x01

and 
PickleSerializer().dumps({1: 12, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 3, 10: 12, 15: 4}) gives the following output

> '\x80\x02}q\x01(K\x01K\x0cK\x02K\x03K\x03K\x04K\x04K\x02K\x06K\x02K\x07K\x02K\x08K\x03K\nK\x0cK\x0fK\x04u.'

I am struggling to see how to sort this issue out.Any help is highly appreciated
Thanks in advance!
-Satish

Comment: This has nothing to do with pickling or is not even reproducible with the code you've shown. It is all about numpy types in your variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you please elaborate, as I supplied the same dictionary in both cases but in one case directly and in the other case as a n assigned variable.

Comment: I would be easier to answer if you provide a [mcve].